# OpenGL and SFML Clock not restarting correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I am currently working making a maze game with OpenGL.

I want to create a timer to keep track of the time that the user spends completing each maze. I am using the SFML Clock to try to keep track of this time.

I have the following set up for the first maze:
maze.draw();

```
    if(mazeOneIteration == 1){
        mazeOneIteration++;
        mazeOneClock.restart();
    }
    char timeStr1[100];
    char levelStr[100];


    sprintf(levelStr, "Level: %d", levelNum);
    sprintf(timeStr1, "Time: %.2fs", mazeOneClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());

    //std::cout << timeStr1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << mazeOneClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() << std::endl;

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(glm::mat4(1.0)));

    box.draw();

    text.setFontSize(20);
    text.draw("User: zsloan112" , 20, 15);
    text.draw(levelStr, getSize().x - 100, getSize().y - 20);
    text.draw(timeStr1, 20, getSize().y - 20);
```

Since this is running in my game loop this block of code is being run 60 times per second, so I only one to restart and set the clock to 0 the very first time it is ran, hence the if statement restarting the clock.

My issue is that when I use `sprintf` to insert the time into the `timeStr1` and it is displayed the time stays at 0 seconds.

How would I get the clock to correctly restart once the first time this block of code is executed, then continue to count the time?

Comment: Why are you using `sprintf`? Isn't `std::string` good enough for you? Why aren't you using `std::chrono`? What value is mazeOneIteration at the beginning of the function?

Comment: @Clearer I have `mazeOneIteration = 1` at the start of the function. I am using sprintf to simply format the time value into the string.

Comment: I think it's because your `mazeOneIteration` is always 1, so it will restart the clock. That's why your time is always displayed as 0. Try to remove the if-statement. If the time is still 0, there might be an other issue at hand.

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, each time it ran the code above the snippet it would set the value to one hence always restarting. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to provide you with a bit of criticism on your code. I you where applying for a job and showed me this code, I wouldn't hire you.

You using `sprintf`. This is a particularly bad sign. Not only are you using `sprintf`, you're also using it with a fixed size array of char. While it's probably going to be fine in this example, it's indicative of a deeper problem. In C++, you should *never* find any of the `s*printf` functions -- there's simply no use for it. Instead just use `std::string`. It will allow you to do exactly what you need without *any* potential problems:

Replace:

```
char timeStr1[100];
char levelStr[100];


sprintf(levelStr, "Level: %d", levelNum);
sprintf(timeStr1, "Time: %.2fs", mazeOneClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds());
```

With:

```
auto const levelStr = "Level: "s + std::to_string(level);
auto const timeStr1 = "Time: "s + mazeOneClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
```

Second, look into `std::chrono`. Not because it's better per say, but simply because it's part of the standard library. SFML is from before `std::chrono` existed, so it's no surprise that it has it's own clock, but you should stick to the standard library when you have no reason not to.

When you're trying to measure elapsed time, `std::chrono::steady_clock` should be your default option.

Things to read:

1. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string
2. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock